# How to get Qt 4/5 to build using VS2012 while targeting Windows XP?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qt4, qt5

I'm trying to build Qt 4.8.5 / Qt 5.2.1 using Visual Studio 2012, targeting Windows XP (SDK v7.1a). There are various incompatibilities of the source with SDK v7.1a while compiled with VS2102, so it doesn't work out of the box.

This is to be a canonical question that provides the knowledge necessary to successfully build Qt in such an environment.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the build environment needs to be prepared as below. Caveat emptor: There are variants of this script "out there" that have typos that make it, effectively, a no-op.

```
@call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
:: The below applies to XP-targeting builds *only*!
@set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
@set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
@set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
```

### Qt 5.2

First, we note that Qt sources should be kept pristine, so that existing builds aren't broken. We shall not change the existing make specs. Thus:

1. Create a separate `win32-msvc2012-xp` qmake spec by copying it from `qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012`. Modify it.
2. Teach configure and qmake makefile about the new qmake spec.
3. Force bootstrap of configure.exe by creating an empty .gitignore file in qtbase.

The script and the patch below handle the process.

```
:: Assume that we're in an equivalent of C:\Qt prefix
@set PREFIX=%~dp0
:: Qt sources
@set QT=%PREFIX%..\5.2.1-src
:: Patch file(s)
@set SRC=%PREFIX%
@set SPEC=win32-msvc2012
@if not exist "%QT%\qt.pro" ( echo Qt source folder expected in %QT%>&2 & exit /b 1 )
::
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5fixes.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5fixes.patch
::
@echo > %QT%\qtbase\.gitignore
@mkdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5xp.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5xp.patch
```

To **undo** the changes, run the following (the variables must be set as above):

```
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5xp-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5xp.patch
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@del %QT%\qtbase\.gitignore
```

The build is then performed by executing:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2012-xp
jom (or nmake)
jom install (if doing the build separate from the installation directory)
```

This make spec also supports static builds (given `-static` to configure), with the caveat that the MSVC2012 runtime is still dynamically linked. Support for static MSVC runtime is a subject of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21862989/1329652).

```
# qt5fixes.patch
# Fix for QTBUG-32519: Fix for preprocessor.lib not getting installed
--- qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/preprocessor/preprocessor.pro 2014-02-01 22:37:36.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/preprocessor/preprocessor.pro 2014-02-18 18:11:00.472660600 -0500
@@ -4,6 +4,10 @@

 include(../../config.pri)

+contains(QT_CONFIG, static) {
+    load(qt_installs)
+}
+
 INCLUDEPATH = $$ANGLE_DIR/src/compiler/preprocessor

 DEFINES += _SECURE_SCL=0
# Fix for QTBUG-32519: Fix for translator_common.lib not getting installed
--- qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/translator_common.pro 2014-02-01 22:37:36.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/translator_common.pro 2014-02-18 18:08:51.596661200 -0500
@@ -4,6 +4,10 @@

 include(../config.pri)

+contains(QT_CONFIG, static) {
+    load(qt_installs)
+}
+
 # Mingw 4.7 chokes on implicit move semantics, so disable C++11 here
 win32-g++*: CONFIG -= c++11

# Fix for QTBUG-32519: Fix for translator_hlsl.lib not getting installed
--- qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/translator_hlsl.pro   2014-02-01 22:37:36.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/translator_hlsl.pro   2014-02-18 18:09:54.651312600 -0500
@@ -4,6 +4,10 @@

 include(../config.pri)

+contains(QT_CONFIG, static) {
+    load(qt_installs)
+}
+
 # Mingw 4.7 chokes on implicit move semantics, so disable C++11 here
 win32-g++*: CONFIG -= c++11

# Fix for QTBUG-36951: Make ANGLE binary compatible with rest of Qt
--- qtbase/src/angle/src/config.pri 2014-02-01 15:37:36.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/angle/src/config.pri 2014-02-20 04:26:52.535186300 -0500
@@ -54,7 +54,6 @@
 CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     DEFINES += _DEBUG
 } else {
-    CONFIG += rtti_off
     DEFINES += NDEBUG
 }
```

```
# qt5xp.patch
# XP Targeting Support for Qt 5.2
#
# Get configure to recognize all qmake specs that begin with a known prefix.
--- qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp  2014-02-01 15:37:29.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp  2014-02-18 13:14:37.321371600 -0500
@@ -149,23 +149,23 @@

 Compiler Environment::compilerFromQMakeSpec(const QString &qmakeSpec)
 {
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2013"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2013")))
         return CC_NET2013;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2012"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2012")))
         return CC_NET2012;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2010"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2010")))
         return CC_NET2010;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2008"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2008")))
         return CC_NET2008;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2005"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2005")))
         return CC_NET2005;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-msvc2003"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-msvc2003")))
         return CC_NET2003;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-icc"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-icc")))
         return CC_INTEL;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-g++"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-g++")))
         return CC_MINGW;
-    if (qmakeSpec == QLatin1String("win32-borland"))
+    if (qmakeSpec.startsWith(QLatin1String("win32-borland")))
         return CC_BORLAND;
     return CC_UNKNOWN;
 }
# Build configure with XP targeting.
--- qtbase/configure.bat    2014-02-01 15:37:23.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/configure.bat    2014-02-18 13:22:34.356160100 -0500
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
 for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%V in (`findstr QT_VERSION_STR %QTSRC%\src\corelib\global\qglobal.h`) do @echo QTVERSION = %%~V>> Makefile
 if not "%cl.exe%" == "" (
     echo CXX = cl>>Makefile
-    echo EXTRA_CXXFLAGS =>>Makefile
+    echo EXTRA_CXXFLAGS = -D_USING_V110_SDK71_>>Makefile
     rem This must have a trailing space.
     echo QTSRC = %QTSRC% >> Makefile
     set tmpl=win32
# Build qmake with XP targeting.
--- qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-20 12:24:10.341305900 -0500
+++ qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-20 12:28:23.316380600 -0500
@@ -42,6 +42,9 @@
               -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS \
               -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM \
               -DUNICODE -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY
+!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp"
+CFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE) -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
+!endif
 CFLAGS   = -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CPPFLAGS)

 CXXFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE)
# Let qmake recognize the XP targeting makespec
--- qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-01 22:37:30.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-17 16:21:09.329949100 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2013" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
+!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2013" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"

 !if "$(SOURCE_PATH)" == ""
 SOURCE_PATH = ..

# XP targeting makespec
--- qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-xp/qmake.conf 2014-02-01 22:37:38.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-xp/qmake.conf 2014-02-17 16:08:47.204498000 -0500
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
 MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = MSBUILD
 QMAKE_PLATFORM          = win32
 CONFIG                 += incremental flat precompile_header autogen_precompile_source debug_and_release debug_and_release_target embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe
-DEFINES                += UNICODE WIN32
+DEFINES                += UNICODE WIN32 _USING_V110_SDK71_
 QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES += _MSC_VER=1700 _WIN32
 contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
     DEFINES += WIN64
@@ -69,8 +69,13 @@
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE    = /INCREMENTAL:NO
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO = /DEBUG /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG      = /DEBUG
-QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
-QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
+contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
+   QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.02
+   QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.02
+} else {
+   QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01
+   QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01
+}
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_EXE        = \"/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type=\'win32\' name=\'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\' version=\'6.0.0.0\' publicKeyToken=\'6595b64144ccf1df\' language=\'*\' processorArchitecture=\'*\'\"
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_DLL        = /DLL
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_LTCG       = /LTCG
# Add support for XP targeting.
--- qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_win.cpp 2014-02-01 22:37:36.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_win.cpp 2014-02-17 16:20:29.612858300 -0500
@@ -571,7 +571,7 @@
 // FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS has been extended by FileIdInfo = 18 as of VS2012.
 typedef enum { Q_FileIdInfo = 18 } Q_FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS;

-#  if defined(Q_CC_MINGW) || (defined(Q_CC_MSVC) && _MSC_VER < 1700)
+#  if defined(Q_CC_MINGW) || (defined(Q_CC_MSVC) && _MSC_VER < 1700) || (defined(Q_CC_MSVC) && _MSC_VER >= 1700 && defined(_USING_V110_SDK71_))

 // MinGW-64 defines FILE_ID_128 as of gcc-4.8.1 along with FILE_SUPPORTS_INTEGRITY_STREAMS
 #    if !(defined(Q_CC_MINGW) && defined(FILE_SUPPORTS_INTEGRITY_STREAMS))
# Add support for XP targeting.
--- qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp  2014-02-17 17:29:02.552706900 -0500
+++ qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp  2014-02-17 17:25:26.662602800 -0500
@@ -435,7 +435,7 @@
     UINT result = QS_TIMER | QS_INPUT | QS_RAWINPUT;
     // QTBUG 28513, QTBUG-29097, QTBUG-29435: QS_TOUCH, QS_POINTER became part of
     // QS_INPUT in Windows Kit 8. They should not be used when running on pre-Windows 8.
-#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1700
+#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1700 && !defined(_USING_V110_SDK71_)
     if (QSysInfo::WindowsVersion < QSysInfo::WV_WINDOWS8)
         result &= ~(QS_TOUCH | QS_POINTER);
 #endif //  _MSC_VER >= 1700
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.3 and onwards do not need any additional patches: Just run configure with "-target xp".

You need to set up the right environment though, like suggested in the other answers

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_
```

(The CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_ prevents a lot of warnings from Windows headers).

Comment: "The CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_ prevents a lot of warnings from Windows headers" This should be included in the makespecs, I consider it a bug if you have to add it manually. It's not merely about "warnings", without this define your binaries will be subtly broken and can lead you on wild goose chases. Don't ask how I know.

Answer (score 0):

The build environment needs to be prepared as below. Caveat emptor: There are variants of this script "out there" that have typos that make it, effectively, a no-op.

```
@call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
:: The below applies to XP-targeting builds *only*!
@set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
@set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
@set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
```

### Qt 4.8

The following script patches the sources:

```
:: Assume that we're in an equivalent of C:\Qt prefix
@set PREFIX=%~dp0
:: Qt sources
@set QT=%PREFIX%..\4.8.5-src
:: Patch file(s)
@set SRC=%PREFIX%
@set SPEC=win32-msvc2012
@if not exist "%QT%\projects.pro" ( echo Qt source folder expected in %QT%>&2 & exit /b 1 )
::
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4fixes.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4fixes.patch
::
@mkdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4xp.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4xp.patch
```

To undo the changes, run the below:

```
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4static-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4static.patch
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
```

The build is then performed by executing:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2012-xp
jom (or nmake)
```

```
# qt4fixes.patch
#
# Fix for HashSet under MSVC2012/2013.
--- src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h 2013-06-07 09:16:54.000000000 -0400
+++ src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h 2013-09-27 12:20:48.148285400 -0400
@@ -174,12 +174,23 @@
         return m_impl.template contains<T, Adapter>(value);
     }

+   /*
     template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
     inline pair<typename HashSet<T, U, V>::iterator, bool> HashSet<T, U, V>::add(const ValueType& value)
     {
         return m_impl.add(value);
     }
+   */
+   // fix
+   template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
+   inline pair<typename HashSet<T, U, V>::iterator, bool> HashSet<T, U, V>::add(const ValueType& value)
+   {
+       typedef typename HashSet<T, U, V>::iterator iter_type;
+       auto& temp = m_impl.add(value);
+       return make_pair((iter_type)temp.first, temp.second);
+   }

+   /*
     template<typename Value, typename HashFunctions, typename Traits>
     template<typename T, typename HashTranslator>
     inline pair<typename HashSet<Value, HashFunctions, Traits>::iterator, bool>
@@ -188,6 +199,18 @@
         typedef HashSetTranslatorAdapter<ValueType, ValueTraits, T, HashTranslator> Adapter;
         return m_impl.template addPassingHashCode<T, T, Adapter>(value, value);
     }
+   */
+   // fix
+   template<typename Value, typename HashFunctions, typename Traits>
+   template<typename T, typename HashTranslator>
+   inline pair<typename HashSet<Value, HashFunctions, Traits>::iterator, bool>
+   HashSet<Value, HashFunctions, Traits>::add(const T& value)
+   {
+       typedef HashSetTranslatorAdapter<ValueType, ValueTraits, T, HashTranslator> Adapter;
+       typedef typename HashSet<Value, HashFunctions, Traits>::iterator iter_type;
+       auto& temp = m_impl.template addPassingHashCode<T, T, Adapter>(value, value);
+       return make_pair((iter_type)temp.first, temp.second);
+   }

     template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
     inline void HashSet<T, U, V>::remove(iterator it)
```

```
# qt4xp.patch
# XP Targeting Support for Qt 4.8
#
# Build configure with XP targeting
--- tools/configure/configure.pro   2013-06-07 09:17:02.000000000 -0400
+++ tools/configure/configure.pro   2014-02-20 10:00:29.840317000 -0500
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
 CONFIG   += console flat stl rtti_off
 CONFIG   -= moc qt
 DEFINES  = UNICODE QT_NODLL QT_NO_CODECS QT_NO_TEXTCODEC QT_NO_UNICODETABLES QT_LITE_COMPONENT QT_NO_STL QT_NO_COMPRESS QT_NO_THREAD QT_NO_QOBJECT QT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
+win32-msvc2012-xp: DEFINES += _USING_V110_SDK71_
 DEFINES  += QT_BOOTSTRAPPED

 win32 : LIBS += -lole32 -ladvapi32
@@ -19,7 +20,7 @@
     QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG -= -MDd
     QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -MTd
 }
-win32-msvc2012: DEFINES += _ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS
+win32-msvc2012*: DEFINES += _ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS

 PRECOMPILED_HEADER = configure_pch.h

# Build qmake with XP targeting
--- qmake/Makefile.win32    2013-06-07 09:17:02.000000000 -0400
+++ qmake/Makefile.win32    2014-02-20 09:31:51.090426700 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
+!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"

 !if "$(SOURCE_PATH)" == ""
 SOURCE_PATH = ..
# Build qmake with XP targeting
--- qmake/Makefile.win32    2013-06-07 09:17:02.000000000 -0400
+++ qmake/Makefile.win32    2014-02-20 09:31:51.090426700 -0500
@@ -42,6 +42,9 @@
               -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICODE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREAD \
               -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED \
               -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT
+!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp"
+CFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE) -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
+!endif
 CFLAGS   = -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS)

 CXXFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE)
--- mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-xp/qmake.conf    2013-06-07 09:17:00.000000000 -0400
+++ mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-xp/qmake.conf    2014-02-17 16:17:38.831119700 -0500
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@
 TEMPLATE                = app
 CONFIG                  += qt warn_on release incremental flat link_prl precompile_header autogen_precompile_source copy_dir_files debug_and_release debug_and_release_target embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe
 QT                      += core gui
-DEFINES                 += UNICODE WIN32
+DEFINES                 += UNICODE WIN32 _USING_V110_SDK71_
 QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES  += _MSC_VER=1700 WIN32

 QMAKE_CC                = cl
@@ -59,8 +59,8 @@
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE    = /INCREMENTAL:NO
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO = /DEBUG /OPT:REF
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG      = /DEBUG
-QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
-QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
+QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01
+QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_EXE        = \"/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type=\'win32\' name=\'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\' version=\'6.0.0.0\' publicKeyToken=\'6595b64144ccf1df\' language=\'*\' processorArchitecture=\'*\'\"
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_DLL        = /DLL
 QMAKE_LFLAGS_LTCG       = /LTCG

# Recognize spec prefixes.
--- src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/WebCore.pri  2013-06-07 09:16:56.000000000 -0400
+++ src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/WebCore.pri  2013-09-27 12:20:48.148285400 -0400
@@ -303,7 +303,7 @@
 }

 # Remove whole program optimizations due to miscompilations
-win32-msvc2005|win32-msvc2008|win32-msvc2010|wince*:{
+win32-msvc2005*|win32-msvc2008*|win32-msvc2010*|win32-msvc2012*|wince*:{
     QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG -= -GL
     QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_LTCG -= -GL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this great tutorial!

I could successfully repeat it on Win7 with Qt 4.8.5-1 (see note below).

I want to add some points I have to struggle with:

On windows a patch tool is required. I used [GnuWin32 patch package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm), which has to be run as administrator, unfortunately. In the patch script I included the entire path to the patch binary.

```
E:\Qt\enterprise-src-4.8.5_patch_for_build\patch-2.5.9-7-bin\bin\patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4fixes.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4fixes.patch
```

To allow the different platform specs in parallel on the same machine, I did an "out-of-source" build. Therefore create a new folder, e.g. `4.8.5_static-xp_build`, start a command prompt, run the "build environment" script, change to the created folder and set the PATH for qmake (`set PATH=%cd%\bin;%PATH%`).

Finally call the configure from the source folder, in my case for example:

```
E:\Qt\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-4.8.5-1\configure -platform win32-msvc2012-static-xp -make nmake -no-phonon -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-declarative -nomake examples -static
```

And a final hint: The Qt 4.8 undo patch script is not correct, it is supposed to undo the `qt4xp.patch` and the `qt4fixes.patch` and **not** the `qt4static.patch`...

Note: I could compile Qt 4.8.5-1 with the variations: xp, static and static-xp. The Qt Demo of the last could be run on a WinXP without redistributables and Qt DLL. Unfortunately I did not succeed to run my own executable, which was compiled with VS2012 IDE. Compiling with nmake works...

Comment: You can change the manifest of the patch tool so as not to have to run it as the administrator. This can be done on the binary of the tool. I had to do it too, although I didn't note how I did it. If you google enough, you'll figure out out :)